# USB 3.0 otg connected in high speed not in SuperSpeed

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, android, usb-3

I am trying to connect USB 3.0 pen drive using OTG cable with my board. But it is always connected in High Speed mode and not in SuperSpeed mode.
I am using android marshmellow as operating system.

Below is my logs when connected pen drive using otg cable in usb 3.0.

```
[ 1180.791471] init: Starting service 'wfdservice'...
[ 1180.817831] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2617) exited with status 1
[ 1180.823813] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2617) killing any children in process group
[ 1184.996960] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=SUSPENDED
[ 1185.060843] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:19:54.036257626 UTC
[ 1185.076653] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:19:54.052092939 UTC
[ 1185.164381] dwc3 6a00000.dwc3: request ffffffc033964b00 was not queued to ep0out
[ 1185.164898] msm-dwc3 6a00000.ssusb: DWC3 in low power mode
[ 1185.170838] android_work: android_work: sent uevent USB_STATE=DISCONNECTED
[ 1185.174512] read descriptors
[ 1185.174607] read strings
[ 1185.204638] init: Starting service 'wfdservice'...
[ 1185.224892] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2622) exited with status 1
[ 1185.230521] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2622) killing any children in process group
[ 1186.179483] init: Untracked pid 2610 exited with status 0
[ 1190.193860] init: Starting service 'wfdservice'...
[ 1190.221855] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2623) exited with status 1
[ 1190.227396] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2623) killing any children in process group
[ 1191.243877] msm-dwc3 6a00000.ssusb: DWC3 exited from low power mode
[ 1191.247675] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[ 1191.256338] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[ 1191.256745] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: irq 804, io mem 0x06a00000
[ 1191.257437] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:20:00.232274447 UTC
[ 1191.268358] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[ 1191.268401] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 1191.268426] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 1191.268459] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.18.20-g9c6c034-dirty xhci-hcd
[ 1191.268483] usb usb3: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.1.auto
[ 1191.273544] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:20:00.249013562 UTC
[ 1191.282095] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1191.282262] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[ 1191.284426] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[ 1191.285214] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[ 1191.286168] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[ 1191.286179] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 1191.286187] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 1191.286194] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.18.20-g9c6c034-dirty xhci-hcd
[ 1191.286200] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:20:00.261711635 UTC
[ 1191.288879] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:20:00.264407364 UTC
[ 1191.302832] usb usb4: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.1.auto
[ 1191.306483] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1191.306575] hub 4-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[ 1191.864273] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[ 1192.015270] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5590
[ 1192.015332] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1192.015370] usb 3-1: Product: Ultra
[ 1192.015400] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 1192.015430] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 4C531001571111109275
[ 1192.027256] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1192.033546] scsi host1: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 1193.047251] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1193.147859]  sdg: sdg1
[ 1194.613417] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1195.244878] init: Starting service 'wfdservice'...
[ 1195.275236] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2628) exited with status 1
[ 1195.281284] init: Service 'wfdservice' (pid 2628) killing any children in process group
[ 1195.644491] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: remove, state 4
[ 1195.644627] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 1195.663814] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: USB bus 4 deregistered
[ 1195.667451] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: remove, state 4
[ 1195.667632] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 1195.679791] healthd: battery l=50 v=0 t=20.0 h=3 st=3 c=0 chg= 1970-01-01 00:20:04.655197622 UTC
```

I want to use my pen drive in SuperSpeed mode. My usb 3.0 driver is dwc3 so is there any changes in driver or dts file is needed for this?

Comment: does your *board* do USB 3.0? What sort of connector is the OTG cable connected by?

Comment: I use OTG cable which support USB 3.0. And It's USB 3.0 micro B connector in my board. So i think it has to be connected in SuperSpeed mode.

Comment: Did you try any other brand or sample of USB 3.0 pen drive?

Comment: No, i only try with this sandisk ultra 3.0 pen drive. this pen drive detected in SuperSpeed in usb 3.0 port but in that case pen drive is direct connected with usb 3.0 host connector not using OTG cable

Answer (score 0):

As you say, your "board" has USB 3.0 micro-B connector. Therefore the board is not an officially recognized "OTG" (aka "Dual-Data-Role" port) device, because for OTG case the board connector must be of micro-A/B type. Therefore the use of your "board" as USB host is outside the user-intended use. There could be at least three reasons why your Sandisk flash does not connect at USB 3.0 SuperSpeed rate:

1. The pen drive is marginal/faulty in SS mode;
2. For normal OTG mode the plug-in connector must be of u-A type (square housing). Therefore to turn the port into host mode you have to use the "OTG cable" with u-B end, wich is formally illegal by USB standard, and therefore cannot be eligible for USB-IF certification. Non-certified USB cables can be very sloppy made and have very bad signal integrity, and might not work with marginal devices and falls back into USB 2.0 mode.
3. The fact that the "board" works in host mode does not mean that it must/will support all USB modes. The most frequent use of USB 3.0 port on portable devices in OTG mode is for debug purposes (UART-style ADB mode), and the "board" can be only partially configured at firmware level, and support only USB 2.0 data rate.

Your log seems to indicate that the Sandisk drive was connected, and then disconnects in 1.5 seconds, for whatever reason.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, pen drive is working in SuperSpeed i checked it in other borad and pc. This board is come to SuperSpeed in device mode but when trying to connect in host mode using OTG it is connect in high speed mode.